# Loading font from node_modules in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, webpack, node-modules

I'm installing a npm package that uses fonts like:

```
var _font = _interopRequireDefault(require("../../style/fonts/font123.eot"));
```

When i start my nextjs project, it returns me this error:

[Error before webpack loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPiGU.png)

To fix this issue, I placed a webpack loader on next.config.js:

```
config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot|svg)$/,
  loader: 'file-loader',
  options: {
    name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]'
  }
});
```

But it fails to parse every font, not only .eot files.

[error after adding webpack loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnLgv.png)

I already tried many webpack loaders and nothing seems to work

Comment: I've also experienced the same problem. I've typically used the package "next-fonts" for this, but it has started failing recently. I'll let you know if I find a fix for it

Comment: @b1nd  I am using next-transpile-modules. It solves my error but makes the app too slow in development.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem, resolved it with this config.

```
module.exports = {
  webpack(config, options) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot|svg)$/,
      loader: "file-loader",
      options: {
        esModule: false,
        name: "[name].[ext]",
        outputPath: "static/media/fonts/",
        publicPath: "../assets/fonts/",
      },
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

[Here](https://antoncodes.com/article/importing-font-awesome-into-nextjs) is an article that can help you more.